Series of stories about different potential second comings or antichrist potentials
There were several and would end up not being the ones. It was set in the future and I think one possibility was a cloned woman who had some powers, and another potential was a dragon, possibly in a virtual reality internet type of environment.
It had humorous elements, as I recall. I think they were short stories. Been scouring the Internet but can't find it. Read them back in the early 2000s, I believe.

Did you read these in an anthology? Online?

It was individual files I think, just online

I believe I downloaded it from a place with legit free indie novels and out of date online books, this was an indie I'm pretty sure
